# How to migrate to a token based login approach- iOS application?

Tags: ios, authentication, touch-id

First of all, I know that this is a very broad question and may not look appropriate. But, I just want to get a heads-up on this item so that I get move in the right direction.

We have an existing iOS application where we depend on backend RESTful web services. We have username/password based authentication in place. The user has to enter the credentials every time he/she wants to login.

Now, we are moving to Touch ID based biometric authentication and hence the idea is to implement a token based authentication  mechanism so that we don't have to store the user password in keychain (which is secured but not completely on a rooted device).

I know that there are multiple ways to implement token based authentication. If someone can help me with any good library or changes to do server and client side, it would be of great help. Thanks.

Please let me know if you need any clarifications.